# How to make new pandas column based on multiple conditionals including 'isnull', 'or' and if colB 'isin' colA -like statements?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, series

First time asking. Is there a way to get a new df column including all three statements (or, isnull-like, isin-like) without iterating over a `for` loop/ keeping code within the spirit of Pandas? I've tried advice from several threads dealing with individual aspects of common conditional problems, but every iteration I've tried usually leads me to *"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."* or produces incorrect results. Below is example data and code from several attempts. My goal is to produce a dataframe (printed below) where the last (new) column concatenates all words from the company and unit columns, (1) without any NaNs (note: 'unit_desc' contains no null values irl, so NaNs in 'comp_unit' mean my function isn't working properly) and (2) without repeating the company name (because sometimes 'unit_desc' already [incorrectly] contains the company name, as with example row 2).

**Desired dataframe**

| company | unit_desc | comp_new | comp_unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Generic | Some description | NaN | Some description |
| NaN | Unit with features | NaN | Unit with features |
| Some LLC | Some LLC Xtra cool space | Some LLC | Some LLC Xtra cool space |
| Another LLC | Unit with features | Another LLC | Another LLC Unit with features |
| Another LLC | Basic unit | Another LLC | Another LLC Basic unit |
| Some LLC | basic unit | Some LLC | Some LLC basic unit |

**Imports and initial example df**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'company': ['Generic', np.nan, 'Some LLC', 'Another LLC', 'Another LLC', 'Some LLC'], 
    'unit_desc': ['Some description', 'Unit with features', 'Some LLC Xtra cool space', 'Unit with features', 'Basic unit', 'basic unit'],
    })
```

**ATTEMPT 0: Uses np.where**
**ATTEMPT 0 Results: ValueError as above**

```
def my_func(df, unit, comp, bad_info_list):
    """Return new dataframe with new column combining company and unit descriptions

    Args:
        df (DataFrame): Pandas dataframe with product and brand info
        unit (str): name of unit description column
        comp (str): name of company name column
        bad_info_list (list): list of unwanted terms
    """

    # (WORKS) Make new company column filtering out unwanted terms
    df["comp_new"] = df[comp].apply(lambda x: x if x not in bad_info_list else np.nan)
    # (!!!START OF NOT WORKING!!!)
    # Make new column with brand and product descriptions
    df["comp_unit"] = np.where(
        (df["comp_new"].isnull().all() or df["comp_new"].isin(df[unit])),
        df[unit],
        (df["comp_new"] + " " + df[unit]),
    )
    # (!!!END OF NOT WORKING!!!)
    
    return df

df_new = my_func(df, "unit_desc", "company", bad_info_list=["Generic", "Name"])
print(df_new)
```

**ATTEMPT 1: Uses `np.where` with ValueError suggestions as indicated with inline comments**
**ATTEMPT 1 Results:**

- Using .all(): Seems to consider all matches over entire Series, so produces wrong results
- Using .any(): Seems to consider any matches over entire Series, so produces wrong results
- Using .item(): Seems to check size of entire Series, so produces ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
- Using .bool(): Returns same ValueError as before

```
def my_func(df, unit, comp, bad_info_list):

    # (WORKS) Make new company column filtering out unwanted terms
    df["comp_new"] = df[comp].apply(lambda x: x if x not in bad_info_list else np.nan)
    # (!!!START OF NOT WORKING!!!)
    # Make new column with brand and product descriptions
    df["comp_unit"] = np.where(
        ((df["comp_new"].isnull().all()) | (df["comp_new"].isin(df[unit]))), # Swap .all() with other options
        df[unit],
        (df["comp_new"] + " " + df[unit]),
    )
    # (!!!END OF NOT WORKING!!!)
    
    return df


df_new = my_func(df, "unit_desc", "company", bad_info_list=["Generic", "Name"])
print(df_new)
```

**ATTEMPT 1.5: Same as 1 except `.isnull().all()` is swapped with `== np.nan`**
**ATTEMPT 1.5: Incorrect results**
I found it odd that I got no ambiguity errors with the `isin` statement---perhaps it's not working as intended?

**ATTEMPT 2: Uses if/elif/else and different suggestions from ValueError**
Seems fixable using for loops for each conditional, but shouldn't there be another way?
**ATTEMPT 2 Results: see bullet points from ATTEMPT 1**

```
def my_func(df, unit, comp, bad_info_list):
    # (WORKS) Make new company column filtering out unwanted terms
    df["comp_new"] = df[comp].apply(lambda x: x if x not in bad_info_list else np.nan)
    # (!!!START OF NOT WORKING!!!)
    if df["comp_new"].isnull(): # Tried .all(), .any(), .item(), etc. just before ":"
        df["comp_unit"] = df[unit]
    elif df["comp_new"].isin(df[unit]): # Tried .all(), etc. just before ":"
        df["comp_unit"] = df[unit]
    else:
        df["comp_unit"] = df["comp_new"] + " " + df[unit]
    # (!!!END OF NOT WORKING!!!)
    
    return df

df_new = my_func(df, "unit_desc", "company", bad_info_list=["Generic", "Name"])
print(df_new)
```

**ATTEMPT 3: Uses if/elif/else combined with apply**
**ATTEMPT 3 Results: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isin'**

```
bad_info_list=["Generic", "Name"]
df["comp_new"] = df["company"].apply(lambda x: x if x not in bad_info_list else np.nan)

def comp_unit_merge(df):
    if df["comp_new"] == np.nan: #.isnull().item():
        return df["unit_desc"]
    elif df["comp_new"].isin(df["unit_desc"]): # AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isin'
        return df["unit_desc"]
    else:
        return df["comp_new"] + " " + df["unit_desc"]
    
df["comp_unit"] = df.apply(comp_unit_merge, axis=1)
print(df)
```

**ATTEMPT 4: Uses np.select(conditions, values)**
**ATTEMPT 4 Result: Incorrect results**
Company name not included in last few rows

```
def my_func(df, unit, comp, bad_info_list):
    # (WORKS) Make new company column filtering out unwanted terms
    df["comp_new"] = df[comp].apply(lambda x: x if x not in bad_info_list else np.nan)
    # (!!!START OF NOT WORKING!!!)
    conditions = [
        ((df["comp_new"] == np.nan) | (df["comp_new"].isin(df[comp]))),
        (df["comp_new"] != np.nan),
    ]
    values = [
        (df[unit]),
        (df["comp_new"] + " " + df[unit]),
    ]
    df["comp_unit"] = np.select(conditions, values)
    # (!!!END OF NOT WORKING!!!)
    
    return df

df_new = my_func(df, "unit_desc", "company", bad_info_list=["Generic", "Name"])
print(df_new)
```

Comment: I tried the first example and it is working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using axis=1, the applied function receives a single row as an argument. Indexing into the row gives you string objects, in most cases -- except where a NaN is encountered.

Numpy NaNs are actually floats. So when you attempt to perform string operations on the company column, like checking whether the unit_desc contains the company, this throws errors for rows that contain NaNs.

Numpy has a function `isnan`, but calling this function on a string also throws an error. So any rows that have an actual company value will cause problems for that check.

You could check the type of the data with `isinstance`, or you could just remove the NaNs from your data ahead of time.

---

This example removes the NaNs ahead of time.

```
badlist=["Generic", "Name"]

def merge(row):
    if row['company'] in badlist:
        return row['unit_desc']
    if row['company'] in row['unit_desc']:
        return row['unit_desc']
    return f"{row['company']} {row['unit_desc']}".strip()

df['company'] = df['company'].fillna('')
df['comp_unit'] = df.apply(merge, axis=1)
print(df)
```

[Here's an online runnable version.](https://www.online-python.com/VsYzKETM7S)

---

Here's an alternative that safely detects the NaNs:

```
badlist=["Generic", "Name"]

def merge(row):
    if isinstance(row['company'], float) and np.isnan(row['company']):
        return row['unit_desc']
    if row['company'] in badlist:
        return row['unit_desc']
    if row['company'] in row['unit_desc']:
        return row['unit_desc']
    return f"{row['company']} {row['unit_desc']}".strip()

df['comp_unit'] = df.apply(merge, axis=1)
print(df)
```

[Here's an online runnable version.](https://www.online-python.com/59u3CZNfQJ)

Comment: The answer from @Filippe was also good and reliable. I prefer this answer, though, because of the readability. Bonus for answers with and without fillna, plus online code link.

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_func(dataframe, unit, comp, bad_info_list):

    df = dataframe.copy()

    df['comp_new'] = df[comp].apply(lambda x: x if x not in bad_info_list else np.nan)

    idx = df[df.apply(lambda x: str(x['comp_new']) in str(x[unit]), axis=1) | df['comp_new'].isnull()].index

    df['comp_unit'] = np.where(
        df.index.isin(idx),
        df[unit],
        df['comp_new'] + ' ' + df[unit]
    )

    return df

new_df = my_func(df, 'unit_desc', 'company', ['Generic', 'Name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas in not good at vectorizing operation between Series (or columns) containing strings, so you will have to use `apply(..., axis = 1)` at a moment. I would just use it once:

```
bad_info_list=["Generic", "Name"]

df_new = df.assign(comp_new = df.apply(
    lambda row: row['unit_desc'] if pd.isna(row['company']) or
    row['company'] in bad_info_list or
    row['unit_desc'].startswith(row['company'])
    else ' '.join(row), axis=1))
```

It makes no change to the original `df` and produces as expected:

```
       company                 unit_desc                        comp_new
0      Generic          Some description                Some description
1          NaN        Unit with features              Unit with features
2     Some LLC  Some LLC Xtra cool space        Some LLC Xtra cool space
3  Another LLC        Unit with features  Another LLC Unit with features
4  Another LLC                Basic unit          Another LLC Basic unit
5     Some LLC                basic unit             Some LLC basic unit
```

Answer (score 0):

first try to fill in Nan values ​​and then just add the two columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'company': ['Generic', np.nan, 'Some LLC', 'Another LLC', 'Another LLC', 'Some LLC'],
    'unit_desc': ['Some description', 'Unit with features', 'Some LLC Xtra cool space', 'Unit with features', 'Basic unit', 'basic unit'],
    })
df = df.fillna('')
df['new_col'] = df['company'] + ' ' + df['unit_desc']

>>>>> df
       company                 unit_desc                            new_col
0      Generic          Some description           Generic Some description
1                     Unit with features                 Unit with features
2     Some LLC  Some LLC Xtra cool space  Some LLC Some LLC Xtra cool space
3  Another LLC        Unit with features     Another LLC Unit with features
4  Another LLC                Basic unit             Another LLC Basic unit
5     Some LLC                basic unit                Some LLC basic unit
```

Comment: I appreciate the fillna suggestion, but your code is missing the company name filter to get rid of terms in 'bad_info_list'? ("Generic" shouldn't show up in 'new_col').

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, "Attempt 0" was close, but the condition was incorrect.  Try this instead:

```
df["comp_unit"] = np.where(
    ((df["comp_new"].isnull()) | (df["comp_new"].apply(lambda row: row['comp_new'] in row[unit], axis='columns'))),
    df[unit],
    (df["comp_new"] + " " + df[unit]),
)
```